# Cannot bind to public property inside ResourceDirectory WinUI3/UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3, xbind

So I am currently trying to bind a public static SolidColorBrush to a "Filled" property on a Rectangle inside a ResourceDirectory Style (inisde App.xaml).
But I always get the Exception

> "Type 'x' used after '{' must be a Markup Extention. Error code 0x09c6."

My xaml code looks like this (inside App.xaml):

```
<Rectangle
    x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
    Width="4"
    Height="24"
    Fill="{x:Bind SomeNamespace:SomeClass.SomeColor}"/>
```

and my codebehind looks like this (inside public class called "SomeClass" in Namespace called "SomeNamespace"):

```
public static SolidColorBrush SomeColor = new(Colors.Red);
```

I know its possible to bind to a public static property with x:Bind in WinUI/UWP but this somehow doesnt work.
I really need to bind from some code behind so I can implement INotifyPropertyChanged so I cant just create a new color resource.
What is the correct way to implement my wanted behavior?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted shows that you are using binding in XAML and it throws an exception.  But next, you are saying that you want to do the binding in code behind. What's the real behavior that you want to get? Please be more specific about the question.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clearly understandable. I want to bind in the xaml so I get the value from some code behind with INotifyPropertyChanged working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't call your PropertyChanged event handler from a static property. You'll need an instance.

Consider storing the brush as a non-static property in a wrapper class. You can instantiate this class as a resource in your App.xaml file and use it across your application.

ColorStorer is a class to store the SolidColorBrush:

```
public class ColorStorer: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    public SolidColorBrush Scb
    {
        get
        {
            return scb;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value as SolidColorBrush != null)
            {
                scb = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Instantiate it in Application.Resources in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ColorStorer x:Key="TestAppColorStorer" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Use it in your views and controls:

```
<Rectangle
            Width="100"
            Height="50"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Fill="{Binding Scb, Source={StaticResource TestAppColorStorer}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```